# How do I re-establish connectivity to the internet (cannot assign addresses now) after setting static ip in openbsd?

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, static-ip, openbsd

I recently asked a question on stackoverflow regarding not being able to push git commits from my OpenBSD (6.3) machine to GitLab, since changing it to a static IP.  It turns out that the problem appears to be one including *all networking outside of the LAN* (routing issue?) not being able to find a route to internet hosts.  I didn't notice at first, because I was doing strictly CLI development work on this machine (via a linux machine w/GUI connecting via the LAN), but the OBSD host is now unable to connect to any external/internet site, giving the error "unable to assign address" for most protocols, "no route to host" from ping, or more vague errors when utilizing lynx.

The only changes that I'd made to things before noticing this issue were **switching to static IP** (utilizing the OBSD Networking FAQ instructions w/OBSD 6.3), and **starting to use *virtualenv* in development**.  Since the issues are persisting outside of the *virtualenv*, I'm guessing that I missed a step about routing w/static IP in the FAQ (which somehow multiple readings of the FAQ subsequently have failed to turn up), or that the static IP change is implicated in some other way.

[Here's my original (misplaced) post on stackoverflow, in case the better description of the troubleshooting/error messages there helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058720/git-push-to-gitlab-suddenly-giving-me-cant-assign-requested-address-could)  I will delete that post upon this being resolved, as it is in the wrong area...

Also, I've tried numerous searches on google, here, and different stackexchange sites, and have been able to turn up any information that seems directly relevant to this issue.  Any pointers to resources, tips, or troubleshooting assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

**Addendum**: Found a little more helpful information; *no default route seems to be set*.  I'm not sure if that's because it's now listed differently in the routing tables under OBSD, or because it has nothing applicable, though, as there is a *hitron.hub* route (my router's manufacturer) that might be handling such.  I've found web hits implicating */etc/mygate*, as well (which I do not have at all), but they're referencing such old versions of OBSD that I'm not sure if they're applicable at all any more.  Hope this helps a bit more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dhcp for the network, it will take care of the routing. For static IPs, you need to add the IP of your gateway to `/etc/mygate`:

```
# echo '1.2.3.4' > /etc/mygate
# sh -x /etc/netstart
```

If the network is still not working for you, reboot the machine.

Comment: Worked wonderfully, with the internal address of the gateway going into /etc/mygate.  Thank you muchly for this clarification, it's really appreciated.